# Is there any Eclipse refactoring API that I can call programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I need to refactor code in a wide term. I know that from inside the Eclipse IDE I can refactor my classes. But is there any API that I can use in a java project so that I can refactor projects dynamically through code?

---

I need some idea on how to achieve the following: a program that calls all the Eclipse refactorings for renaming and moving in a loop to refactoring the entire project in one shot!

---

I don't want to introduce new refactoring types by extending the refactoring classes. I just want to call them programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***The answer below is great, but I answered with a wider perspective for the people who need a more bulky and tasty crunch of this wonderful `cake`:***

```
    RefactoringStatus status = new RefactoringStatus();
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IProject[] projects = root.getProjects();
```

***then:***

```
for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
    IType primary = unit.findPrimaryType();
    IMethod[] methods = primary.getMethods();
    int i = 1;
    for (IMethod method : methods) {
        if (method.isConstructor()) {
            continue;
        }
    makeChangetoMethods(status, method,"changedMethodVersion_" + i);
    ++i;
    }
}
```

***After that:***

```
IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
status = new RefactoringStatus();
Refactoring refactoring = performMethodsRefactoring(status, methodToRename, newName);
```

***then:***

```
Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
change.perform(monitor);
```

***find below the code for setting the `descriptor`:***

```
String id = IJavaRefactorings.RENAME_METHOD;
RefactoringContribution contrib = RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(id);
RenameJavaElementDescriptor desc = contrib.createDescriptor();
desc.setUpdateReferences(true);
desc.setJavaElement(methodToRename);
desc.setNewName(newName);
desc.createRefactoring(status);
```

Answer (score 17):

Something like [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-LTK/ltk.html)?

> Anyone who supports a programming language in an Eclipse-based IDE
>   will be asked sooner or later to offer automated refactorings -
>   similar to what is provided by the Java Development Tools (JDT). Since
>   the release of Eclipse 3.1, at least part of this task (which is by no
>   means simple) is supported by a language neutral API: the Language
>   Toolkit (LTK). But how is this API used?

**EDIT:**

If you want to programmatically run refactorings without using the UI, RefactoringDescriptors (see [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html)) can be used to fill in the parameters and execute the refactoring programmatically.  If you create a plugin that depends on `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and add the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension, you will be able to run an `IApplication` class from eclipse similar to a `main(String[])` class in plain java apps.  An example of calling the API can be found on the [post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/78987/245682/#msg_245682).

```
ICompilationUnit cu = ... // an ICompilationUnit to rename

RefactoringContribution contribution =
    RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(IJavaRefactorings .RENAME_COMPILATION_UNIT);
RenameJavaElementDescriptor descriptor =
    (RenameJavaElementDescriptor) contribution.createDescriptor();
descriptor.setProject(cu.getResource().getProject().getName( ));
descriptor.setNewName("NewClass"); // new name for a Class
descriptor.setJavaElement(cu);

RefactoringStatus status = new RefactoringStatus();
try {
    Refactoring refactoring = descriptor.createRefactoring(status);

    IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
    refactoring.checkInitialConditions(monitor);
    refactoring.checkFinalConditions(monitor);
    Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
    change.perform(monitor);

} catch (CoreException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have more detailed questions about using the JDT APIs (AST, Refactoring, etc) I'd suggest you ask on the [JDT Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/13/).

Comment: I think its a file in your eclipse directory: Core and UI A subclass of org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring must always be created. Check the text at Core and UI and "Action!"

Comment: The LTK APIs allows its refactorings to be configured with an object as opposed to a UI.  While it needs to be an eclipse plugin, you can write a headless IApplication that can fill in the refactoring configuration from the command line and execute it against your workspace.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html is a discussion of the refactoring API.  The `RefactoringDescriptors` can be used to programmitcally set up a change and execute it in an operation without involving the GUI or wizards.

Comment: If you create a plugin that depends on `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and add the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension, you will be able to run an `IApplication` class from eclipse similar to a `main(String[])` class in plain java apps.

Comment: I'm on irc://freenode.net/#eclipse

Comment: Yes, see the article I mentioned and this thread: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/78987/245682/#msg_245682

Comment: When you ran it, did it not work?  The API should still be valid.

Comment: If you'd like to run the refactoring in Eclipse and allow the user to undo it, perform the refactoring using `PerformRefactoringOperation`: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fltk%2Fcore%2Frefactoring%2FPerformRefactoringOperation.html