# Rename a project from Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, refactoring

I have a requirement to Rename a project from eclipse plugin. I have read this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html). I am new to plugin development. If anyone has prev experience can you share me the steps to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

There is org.eclipse.ltk, which enables you to make refactoring. In [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129689/is-there-any-eclipse-refactoring-api-that-i-can-call-programmatically) you can see how to execute refactoring programatically, which includes renaming.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this and this is what we did based on the above referred article.

```
RefactoringContribution contribution = RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(RenameResourceDescriptor.ID);
RenameResourceDescriptor desc = (RenameResourceDescriptor) contribution.createDescriptor();
desc.setProject(null);
desc.setResourcePath(root.getProject(name).getFullPath());
desc.setNewName(newName);

RefactoringStatus status = new RefactoringStatus();
Refactoring refactoring = desc.createRefactoring(status);

refactoring.checkInitialConditions(monitor);
refactoring.checkFinalConditions(monitor);
Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
change.perform(monitor);
```