# How to execute inline refactoring programmatically using JDT/LTK?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-plugin, ltk

I could use `Refactor->Inine` when I need to inline a method.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This the code skeleton that I tried, I used the code in this post - [Is there any eclipse refactoring API that I can call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129689/is-there-any-eclipse-refactoring-api-that-i-can-call-programmatically).

```
// 1. Get ICompiationUnit for type "smcho.Hello"
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject("Hello");
project.open(null /* IProgressMonitor */);

IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
IType itype = javaProject.findType("smcho.Hello");
org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit icu = itype.getCompilationUnit();

// 2. Contribution and Description creation
RefactoringContribution contribution = RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(IJavaRefactorings.INLINE_METHOD);
InlineMethodDescriptor descriptor = (InlineMethodDescriptor) contribution.createDescriptor();

descriptor.setProject(icu.getResource().getProject().getName( ));

// 3. executing the refactoring
RefactoringStatus status = new RefactoringStatus();
try {
    Refactoring refactoring = descriptor.createRefactoring(status);

    IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
    refactoring.checkInitialConditions(monitor);
    refactoring.checkFinalConditions(monitor);
    Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
    change.perform(monitor);
} catch (CoreException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I execute the code, I got this error

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The refactoring script argument 'input' is missing 
in the refactoring script.
```

I think I need to give the refactored method name to the API. What might be wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that works with inline refactoring JDT API.
It requires start position and length to be inlined.

```
int[] selection= {start, length}; // getSelection();
InlineMethodRefactoring refactoring= InlineMethodRefactoring.create(this.icu, new RefactoringASTParser(ASTProvider.SHARED_AST_LEVEL).parse(this.icu, true), selection[0], selection[1]);
refactoring.setDeleteSource(true);
refactoring.setCurrentMode(Mode.INLINE_ALL); // or INLINE SINGLE based on the user's intervention

IProgressMonitor pm= new NullProgressMonitor();
RefactoringStatus res = refactoring.checkInitialConditions(pm);
res = refactoring.checkFinalConditions(pm);

final PerformRefactoringOperation op= new PerformRefactoringOperation(
refactoring, getCheckingStyle());
op.run(new NullProgressMonitor());
```

When you know the name of the method that is going to be inlined, you can use the code in - [Getting startPosition and length of a method invocation using JDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371526/getting-startposition-and-length-of-a-method-invocation-using-jdt)

Answer (score 2):

You never supply the method to the refactoring operation in the above code, you only give it the project context. But I don't know the necessary API for that.

If you look at [this source code](http://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/eclipse-doc36/src-html/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/scripting/InlineMethodRefactoringContribution.html), you will notice the use of JavaRefactoringDescriptorUtil.ATTRIBUTE_INPUT, which is probably the one you also need to set. Maybe you can search the refactoring.ui plugin sources for references to that attribute.