# Change project name in code for an eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm  making a eclipse plugin and I am having trouble figuring out how to change the name of a project in code. As my plugin imports projects and I would like to rename a project if a project with the same name exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you doing the import? You should just be able to change the `IProjectDescription` name during the import.

Comment: the function for setName in IProjectDescription says that it will ignore the new name if there is already a handle. From what I understand the .project is the "handle" so changing the description should not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This thread points to a library that should support it: [Is there any eclipse refactoring API that I can call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129689/is-there-any-eclipse-refactoring-api-that-i-can-call-programmatically)

Comment: Sorry about the vague question. I've updated the main question. I was looking for a way to rename the project in code. So inside my plugin.

Comment: Answer updated - the re-factoring API's support renaming

Comment: I saw that question. Sadly I didn't understand most of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is roughly the code required (adapted from `WizardProjectsImportPage`):

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

IProjectDescription description = workspace.loadProjectDescription(existing .project path);

description.setName("new project name");  // May not be necessary

description.setLocation(null);  // Default location in the workspace

// Create new project handle

IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject("new project name");

// Create and open the project

project.create(description, progress monitor);

project.open(IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, progress monitor);

/// TODO use org.eclipse.ui.wizards.datatransfer.ImportOperation to import project contents
```