# method renaming code in java eclipse for code refactoring

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring

Is there any code could get for renaming method in java eclipse plugin for code re-factoring?

For instance, if want to change method name at one place , it may get changed at all other places.

visit http://pdplab.it.uom.gr/teaching/sunjava/eclipse-java.html

Comment: So you do want it to change everywhere or only the one location?

Comment: I want it throughout the project wherever the method is called

Comment: Right-click->refactor->rename

Comment: want the code for this rename refactoring technique to know how it gets implemented and could make more refactoring techniques accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any eclipse refactoring API that I can call programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129689/is-there-any-eclipse-refactoring-api-that-i-can-call-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

The starting point corresponding to `Refactor >> Rename` is org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.RenameAction. Start by looking at the package org.eclipse.jdt.core.refactoring.descriptors and the class org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring:

```
RefactoringContribution contribution =
RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(IJavaRefactorings.RENAME_METHOD);
RenameJavaElementDescriptor descriptor =
(RenameJavaElementDescriptor) contribution.createDescriptor()
```